# jQuery - Close button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found a script that I needed for my website, but I can't get it work.
Here's the script:
http://jsfiddle.net/vVsAn/1/

But when I try use it ([live example](http://artotek.fi)), it won't work.

Does it matter where I put the script in your HTML? So far I've tried placing it right after the body tag, in head and inside the div, but the result is the same.
I do have jQuery linked from Google's library, but it's like there'd be no jQuery at all.

### jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#hideshow').live('click', function(event) {        
        jQuery('#lang').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

Pardon my ignorance, I'm very new to JavaScript and jQuery.

Comment: Try putting the script at the very bottom of the file... Completely outside all of the html tags.

Comment: It doesn't change anything.

Comment: What Html you have added on the page.. please post that too.... where you've included the jquery script file ???

Comment: @Schokea: 1. Since the script is using `ready`, that won't matter. 2. Putting the script outside of **all** HTML tags is invalid; everything in an HTML page must be a descendant of the `html` element, and the only valid direct children of the `html` element are `head` and `body`. So `script` must be a descendant of `head` or `body`.

Comment: @Milind Anantwar 's answer fixed it. The script however is outside the HTML tags like Schokea adviced. Works just fine there.

Answer (score 2):

`.live` was **removed** in jquery 1.9

**[See DOCs](http://api.jquery.com/live/)**

---

Try using `.on` instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '#hideshow', function(){ 
   //your event function
});
```

**[Working Demo with toggling value](http://jsfiddle.net/vVsAn/1781/)**

Comment: Cool! It works now. By the way, would it be possible to change the close buttons ´value´ on close? Now it says 'Hide', but I'd want the button to say 'show' when it's closed. Thank you.

Comment: @user109899 :i have craeted the fiddle for it. Please see link above.

Comment: Not working, except the button value change when I changed the ´.live´ to ´.on´.

Comment: can you give link to fiddle??

Comment: I have used on in fiddle now.

Comment: Use bind instead of On

Comment: Now if I have two same values, it won't change: http://jsfiddle.net/vVsAn/1785/ I need it be 'Hide' not 'hide'.

Comment: Change your if condition spelling to "Hide"

Comment: It works. But here's another problem: I made a CSS3 button, which doesn't use the 'value' property, but just text. http://jsfiddle.net/vVsAn/1789/

Answer (score 1):

You are using jQuery 1.10.2, the [live method is removed](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed) in jQuery 1.9 so you need to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).on('click', '#hideshow', function(event) {        
        $('#lang').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

Also since the event is binded to the document object there is no need to use the dom ready handler

```
$(document).on('click', '#hideshow', function(event) {        
    $('#lang').toggle('show');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.7 'live()' has been deprecated, use .on() instead ( http://api.jquery.com/live/ )

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(this).on('click', '#hideshow', function(event) {        
        jQuery('#lang').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

Also, remove the ':before' you have prior the javascript which is completely out of context.

By convention, the best place to add javascript is to do it in the 'head' tag, but in the absolute you can put it anywhere and it will work as long as jquery is referenced first.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Make sure that you add the Script inside Body tag or in side Head Tag.
You should not put script after body tag

Secondly let me know which version of jQuery you are using
Live is deprecated since 1.4 and if you are using jquery 1.7+ then use **$("..").on instead**

Comment: I meant after the opening body tag.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `jquery version greater than 1.7`.

`live` has been deprecated from `Jquery 1.7`. Use `on`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vVsAn/1769/)

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery live method deprecated

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9

use older jquery or use other method such as on

Answer (score 0):

live was deprecated, use on click, or even this:

```
    $('#hideshow').click(function(event) {

        //your code here 


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hideshow").click(function(event){
    $("p")('#lang').toggle('show');
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).bind('click', '#hideshow', function(event) {        
        $('#lang').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

or

```
jQuery(function($){
     $(document).click('#hideshow', function(event) {        
         $('#lang').toggle('show');
     });
});
```

Apologies for syntactical slip.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#hideshow').bind('click', function(event) {        
             jQuery('#lang').toggle('show');
            if($(this).val()=="Hide")
                $(this).val("Show")
                else
                $(this).val("Hide")    
        });
```

This can be your best solution